# iMessage not working after changing MAC address

Tags: ios, iphone, messages, apple-id, mac-address

My iMessage is not working after I have changed my MAC address. I have restored my original MAC address, but it is still not working. My phone is an iPhone 4s, 6.1.3 jailbroken.

I changed my DNS, restored with iLex RAT (because I don't want to upgrade to iOS 8), then reset network settings, but it is still not working. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Interesting, so how did you change the MAC ?

Comment: Needless to say you have broken the authentication protocol with iMessage. It is not clear how you "restored" the MAC and if it was done correctly and I do not know if the iLex RAT will do that.

Comment: Why all the up votes? "I pushed some random buttons. I broke stuff. Haalp!!" -1 from me. You'll probably need to get your provider to restore the association, or Apple.

Comment: guys, there is no solution ?

Comment: Try restoring your phone to factory defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I simply signed out of my apple id, signed into a different one, then signed back into my initial one and it worked. Hope it helps.